# What would be the best approach to resume longer texts in one word?

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, natural-language-understanding, seq2seq

I am trying to create a model capable of resuming longer texts (my dataset has up to 140 words for each instance) in a single word (or multiple separate words). The idea is to synthetize positive or negative feedbacks as words like "frustrated", "amazed" etc

In my research I found references to "Seq2Seq" and "Autoencoder" strategies.

I tried to train an Autoencoder neural network but since I am very newbie i hadn't had much success. The Autoencoder sounded like a good ideia because right now the entries in my dataset are not labeled

I was wondering what architecture is the best option in this case

Thanks in advance